# Shuffle linked list in c with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a linked list in `C`.
I've thinking about do it by run all over the list and for each object I'll try to randomize an index and swap between them.
it's seem the code work, but after couple of time I run the code its seem that part of the list is gone, and sometime I get kicked out from the application.

Here is the code:

```c
void main() {
    Song* head = createSong(1, "aaaa", "aaaa");
    Song* song2 = createSong(2, "bbbb", "bbbb");
    Song* song3 = createSong(3, "cccc", "cccc");
    addSongToTheEndOfTheList(head, song2);
    addSongToTheEndOfTheList(head, song3);
    printPlaylist(head);
    shuffleList(head);
    printPlaylist(head);
    //freePlaylist(head);
}
int countList(Song* head) {
    Song* currentSong = head;
    int i = 0;
    if (currentSong)
    {
        while (currentSong->next)
        {
            currentSong = currentSong->next;
            i++;
        }       
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
void swapSong(Song* head,Song* Source, int id) {
    Song* tempSong = (Song*)malloc(sizeof(Song));
    Song* currentSong = head;
    while(currentSong && currentSong->id != id){
        currentSong = currentSong->next;
    }
    if (currentSong) {
        tempSong->id = currentSong->id;
        tempSong->name = currentSong->name;
        tempSong->artist = currentSong->artist;
        tempSong->next = currentSong->next;
        currentSong->id = Source->id;
        currentSong->name = Source->name;
        currentSong->artist = Source->artist;
        currentSong->next = Source->next;
        Source->id = tempSong->id;
        Source->name = tempSong->name;
        Source->artist = tempSong->artist;
        Source->next = tempSong->next;
        free(tempSong);
    }
    else {
        printf("The list is empty.");
    }

}
void shuffleList(Song* head) {
    Song* currentSong = head;
    int listLength = countList(head);
    int randNum;
    srand(time(NULL));
    if (currentSong) {
        for (int i = 1; currentSong;i++) {
            swapSong(head, currentSong, rand()%listLength+1);
            currentSong = currentSong->next;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("The list is empty.");
    }
}
```

The full code is here:
https://pastebin.com/fSS3rrTv

Hope you can help me figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: Use your debugger first.

Comment: Also compile with all warnings enabled, `int *id;` is most likely wrong, you certainly want `int id;` instead. And you probably want `char* name[somelength];` instead of `char* name;`. Read the chapters dealing with strings and the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book.

Comment: You should swap _either_ the data _or_ the list nodes (that is the connectivity of the list); you code does both. In other words, don't touch `next` when you swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies in `swapSong`. There are two possible ways to swap elements in a list:

- either you swap data and do not touch `next` pointers
- or you do not touch data add change pointers

The former is simpler for singly linked list with few internal data (which is your use case), the latter is more for doubly linked lists.

Here just change `swapSong` to:

```
void swapSong(Song* head,Song* Source, int id) {
    Song* tempSong = (Song*)malloc(sizeof(Song));
    Song* currentSong = head;
    while(currentSong && currentSong->id != id){
        currentSong = currentSong->next;
    }
    if (currentSong) {
        tempSong->id = currentSong->id;
        tempSong->name = currentSong->name;
        tempSong->artist = currentSong->artist;
        //tempSong->next = currentSong->next;
        currentSong->id = Source->id;
        currentSong->name = Source->name;
        currentSong->artist = Source->artist;
        //currentSong->next = Source->next;
        Source->id = tempSong->id;
        Source->name = tempSong->name;
        Source->artist = tempSong->artist;
        //Source->next = tempSong->next;
        free(tempSong);
    }
    else {
        printf("The list is empty.");
    }

}
```

---

BTW, in `Song` struct, `id` is declared as an `int *`, while it is used as an `int`. Change to the following to remove some warnings:

```
typedef struct Song {
    int id;
    char* name;
    char* artist;
    struct Song* next;
}Song;
```

And as noticed by @500-InternalServerError, you do not need to allocate anything in `swapSong`: just use a local struct:

```
void swapSong(Song* head,Song* Source, int id) {
    Song* currentSong = head;
    while(currentSong && currentSong->id != id){
        currentSong = currentSong->next;
    }
    if (currentSong) {
        Song tempSong = *currentSong;
        currentSong->id = Source->id;
        currentSong->name = Source->name;
        currentSong->artist = Source->artist;
        Source->id = tempSong.id;
        Source->name = tempSong.name;
        Source->artist = tempSong.artist;
    }
    else {
        printf("The list is empty.");
    }
}
```

Comment: - can of course be further simplified by having `tempSong` not be a pointer.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Of course! I only made the minimal changes to fix the problem.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError how can I make tempSong not as pointer? i need to allocate memory for this, can you show an example?